# Connect fails from paho to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, mqtt, iot, paho

I am trying to connect to AWS using the paho MQTT C library. I have correctly set up my AWS thing and certificates. I tested it by publishing using mosquitto and MQTTFx tools.

I tried mapping the connect URL, certificate files and keys to the parameters needed by MQTTClient.ssl., but the connect call keeps failing.

I can't post the entire code here, so I'll just post the relevant bits.

```
 #define ADDRESS     "ssl://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-2.amazonaws.com:8883"
 #define CLIENTID    "testclient"
 #define TOPIC_REQ   "req/16000393" //this is the topic I'm subscribing to at AWS side (publishing from client laptop)
...
#define CRT_FILE    "./certificate.pem.crt"
#define KEY_FILE    "./private.pem.key"
#define CA_FILE     "./rootCA.pem" 
...
 int main(int argc, char* argv[])
 {
      MQTTClient client;
      MQTTClient_connectOptions conn_opts = MQTTClient_connectOptions_initializer;
      MQTTClient_message pubmsg = MQTTClient_message_initializer;
      MQTTClient_deliveryToken token;

      MQTTClient_SSLOptions sslopts = MQTTClient_SSLOptions_initializer;

      int rc;
      int ch;

      conn_opts.ssl = &sslopts;
      conn_opts.ssl->trustStore = CRT_FILE;
      conn_opts.ssl->keyStore = CA_FILE;
      conn_opts.ssl->privateKey = KEY_FILE;
      conn_opts.ssl->verify = 1;

      MQTTClient_create(&client, ADDRESS, CLIENTID,
          MQTTCLIENT_PERSISTENCE_NONE, NULL);
      conn_opts.keepAliveInterval = 20;
      conn_opts.cleansession = 1;

      MQTTClient_setCallbacks(client, NULL, connlost, msgarrvd, delivered);

      if ((rc = MQTTClient_connect(client, &conn_opts)) != MQTTCLIENT_SUCCESS)
      {
          printf("Failed to connect, return code %d\n", rc);
          exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
...
```

The connection keeps failing. Kindly help! I'm out of ideas.